# Memcached issue

Tags: php, memcached, osx-mavericks, libmemcached

I am working on OSX 10.10.5, using AMPPS 3.2, PHP 5.6. I am trying to install memcached to work with PHP but no luck so far.

What I have done so far:

- I have installed downloading the sources
- Using homebrew (also update it)
- Using pecl

First time I tried I got an error about architecture did not match, then I realized that the PHP version with AMPPS is 32bits and OSX is 64bits so I added this flag: CFLAGS='-arch i386' which solved that issue but now I got another errors:

```
memcached support => enabled
Version => 2.2.0
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _memcached_lib_version
  Referenced from: /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcached.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _memcached_lib_version
  Referenced from: /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcached.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Any ideas?